# Open All Files within Weekly Folder Name (that changes weekly) within Monthly Folder Name

Tags: vba, excel

I have 12 folders (months) and within each month's folder, there is a folder for each week. Within each week's folder there are a load of excel files.

On a weekly basis, I need to open all files within the current week's folder so the data populates the indirect match formulas. Hoping to do this with a click of the button...

Is there a way to reference the path to point to the relevant month and week? E.g. I update a cell in the master file which brings up the month and week, and the VBA points to there and pings open those files? I'm trying to adapt some VBA for another master file I have that just stays within the same folder location.

```
Public Sub test()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "S:\Accounts\FP&A\1. Weekly Sales Figures\FY 18\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    '
    ' CODE GOES HERE
    '
    Filename = Dir

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Loop

ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance,
Ben

***Folder structure***
After the \FY18\ (shown in the filepath above) I have 12 folders (e.g. '03 - Apr 2017' '04 - May 2017' and then within '04 - May 2017' for example, I have the weeks...(e.g. '04.05.2017', '11.05.2017', '18.05.2017'

Hopefully that helps Max? Thanks

Comment: yes, it is possible but you are giving a little less info. I need to know the folder structure and syntax of your folders.

Comment: Hi Max, will edit at the bottom of my question now...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this as a starting point to define your file path,

```
   Dim MonthFolder as String
   Dim DayFolder as String
   Dim Path As String

' These could be referenced from the Current Date or Cell Values, Input Boxes...
' as long as they match your folder structure.
   MonthFolder = May
   DayFolder = 26

   Path = "S:\Accounts\FP&A\" & MonthFolder & "\" & DayFolder & "\"
```